# Relation between members of a set X and a set Y that is a member of X

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be the set $\{1,\{2,3\}\}$ where $Y=\{2,3\}$

1. $Y \subset X$ is false by definition.
2. However $2,3 \in Y$ and $Y \in X.$

I'm not sure if membership can be transitive but if it is true then $2,3 \in X,\;$ which makes  $Y \subset X$ true.

Does this all mean that membership is not transitive and $2,3 \notin X?$

Comment: Membership is **not** transitive. A soccer player John is *member* of the soccer team Blah and the soccer team Blah is member of the Soccer League, but John is **not** member of the Soccer League.

Comment: The members of $X$ are $1$ and $\{2,3\}.$ Neother of those two members is $2$ and neither of them is $3.$ So $2$ and $3$ are not members of $X.$

Comment: Look at your number (2). $2, 3 \in Y$, and $Y\in X$.  That's the way to describe this relation, short of simply stating $X = \{1, Y\},$ where $Y = \{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last sentence/question: You're correct that set-membership is not a transitive relation, as the example you show demonstrates.

$2\in Y,\; 3\in Y.\;$ And $Y = \{2,3\} \in X.\;\;$ But $2 \notin X, \;3\notin X$.

While the subset relation of sets IS transitive ($A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$, then $A\subset C$); however membership is not transitive.

Comment: Thank you. What relation do 2 and 3 bear to X in this case? Is there a word to describe it?

Comment: $a, b $ are elements in the set Y, and $X = \{1, Y\}$